# How to generate core dump file when jvm is alive in IBM-JDK

Tags: java, coredump

I would like to collect the core dump file automatically when JVM is alive.Currently, I invoke an command `kill -6 processId` in a class. Is there any elegant way to do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java API to do this in an IBM Java SDK is here:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.api.80.doc/com.ibm.jvm.ras/com/ibm/jvm/Dump.html